# интерпретатор java

Tags: java

В языке java JVM имеет интерпретатор или нет

Comment: Виртуальные машины Java обычно содержат Интерпретатор байт-кода, однако, для повышения производительности во многих машинах также применяется JIT-компиляция часто исполняемых фрагментов байт-кода в машинный код. https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine

Comment: спасибо что отметили как дубликат. Отдельное спасибо Кириллу Малышеву